# Add vector to existing jTable to show records in database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, vector

I have developed below code,

```
try{
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online_store","username","password");
          if(con != null){

                String query = "SELECT * FROM expense"; 
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                ResultSetMetaData rsmt = rs.getMetaData();
                int c = rsmt.getColumnCount(); 
                Vector column = new Vector(c);

                for(int i = 1; i <= c; i++) { column.add(rsmt.getColumnName(i)); } 
                Vector data = new Vector(); Vector row = new Vector();
                while(rs.next())
                { 
                    row = new Vector(c); 
                    for(int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
                    { 
                        row.add(rs.getString(i)); 
                     } 
                     data.add(row);
                }

              expense_table.add(data);
              //  expense_table.getColumnName(null);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "get details from database");
          }

}catch(SQLException ex){
     System.out.println(ex);
}
```

My existing table's name is expense_table. I need to display all the records from database in this table without change its structure/without creating new table.Everything is ok except showing data(rows) vector in table which is " expense_table.add(data);" line. Please tell me is there any method to to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to display all the records from database in this table without change its structure/without creating new table.

So then you don't need to access the column names from the ResultSet. You just need to add new rows of data to the JTable. So get rid of the logic that creates the "column" Vector.

```
//expense_table.add(data);
```

You can't add a Vector to a JTable. There is no method that allows you to do this so get rid of that statement.

Instead you need to add the data to the `DefaultTableModel` one row at a time:

```
//data.add(row);
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)expense_table.getModel();
model.addRow( row );
```